# How to append to a paragraph above div

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to append additional information to the paragraph above a div?

```
<p>Christan has perfect attendance: Year </p>
<div class="roundbox">
```

I am doing something like this; which adds another paragraph instead of appending to the existing one.

```
$('div.roundbox').prepend('2015-2016');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need target paragraph thus use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) then use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('div.roundbox').prev('p').append('2015-2016');
```

Comment: Thank you! It would have worked perfecly but I realized that the paragraph is in <form> tags. How do I handle that?  `<form name="navigation"><p>Christan has perfect attendance: Year </p> </form><div class="roundbox"></div>`

Comment: @Kaur `$('div.roundbox').prev('form').find('p').append('2015-2016');`

Comment: thanks! I realized that this is the only paragraph in all the pages I want to alter, so I can just use `$('form[name="navigation"]').find('p').append('2015-2016');` One of the pages has additional button in this paragraph. Now I need to figure out how to append this text before the last text in this paragraph. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just use append like this

```
$( "p" ).append( "2015-2016" );
```

If you want to append to a specific paragraph, give it an id

```
<p id="toto">Christan has perfect attendance: Year </p>
```

and then append to the specific p

```
$('#toto').append( "2015-2016" );
```